# What is the most accurate rendering of Psalms 7:11 (Textual Criticism)

Tags: hebrew, psalms, textual-criticism, historical-interpretation

A few different translations:

> “**God judgeth the righteous**, And God is angry with the wicked every
> day.” ‭‭Psalm‬ ‭7:11‬ ‭**KJV**

> “**God is a righteous judge**, And a God who shows indignation every day.”
> ‭‭Psalms‬ ‭7:11‬ ‭**NASB2020**

> “God is a just judge; **he is angry throughout the day**.” ‭‭Psalms‬
> ‭7:11‬ ‭**NET**

> “God, your righteousness is revealed when you judge. ***Because of the
> strength of your forgiveness***, **your anger does not break out every
> day**.” ‭‭Psalms‬ ‭7:11‬ ‭**TPT**‬‬

**Q**: **So which translation is the most accurate from the Hebrew Textual Variants?  Even if the most accurate translation is not listed here.**

Comment: _God `is' a righteous judge, And He is not angry at all times._ Young's Literal Translation

Comment: You state 'Textual Criticism'. Are you disputing the original Hebrew text or just asking about the translation of Hebrew into English ?

Comment: @NigelJ I have a high view of the Authority & Inspiration of Scripture; therefore I am asking about what is the most accurate translation of the Hebrew text.  From Hebrew into English?  Yes.  Why are there so many variants of Psalms 7:11?

Comment: Again, a 'variant' would normally (in Textual Criticism terms) refer to manuscripts which differ from the norm. I take it that you are merely referring to different _translations_ of the Hebrew. The reason ? It is a simple one. Money. People make money out of making 'modern' or 'different' bibles. It is big business. We used to have one bible (the Authorised Version) which lasted hundreds of years. Now, things are different.

Comment: I checked the TPT The Passion Translation, is a terrible commentary, does not even qualify as a translation. So you are basically wrong by comparing translations with a commentary https://www.thepassiontranslation.com/faqs/

Comment: @Michael16 Who?  Me or Nigel?  I found TPT in my Bible app, so I’m confused.

Comment: yes, you coz you posted it in the comparison of translations. It is really a commentary, not a translation. Cannot be used to compare translations like that. Though it seems it used the LXX while interpreting the verse of the topic. You need to check the nature of the bible versions before thinking there is a textual variant.

Comment: @Michael16 Well, I’ve only been studying textual criticism for about 1-2 years now.  I’m not on the same level as Bruce Metzger (of course you never assumed that?) Yet, since it was in my Bible app; I assumed it was textual variant from the Hebrew Manuscripts.  I’ve asked on Quora (separate App) for textual criticism tools (computer tools) no answer so far.  I plan on studying textual criticism for life so this particular mishap is due to human error.  What direction of info gathering would you point me to now?

Comment: @Michael16 Furthermore on my Bible App it literally says: “The Passion Translation”  There is no way for me to tell at first sight that it’s a “commentary”.  If I compared the TPT with the NKJV, I still can’t tell that the TPT is a “commentary”.

Comment: You first need to know that the bible versions (the real ones, not the fake ones like TPT) themselves provide textual variants in footnotes stating that "some mss says this and that" You don't determine textual var by comparing bible versions. Use ESV, NET, like versions which are based on critical editions and provide some info about it. Use theWord.net software, you will find a commentary module "Student's Guide to New Testament Textual Variants" in it. It lists the variants with basic info. For mobile use mybible.zone app. Start learning Greek by Duolingo casually, modern Greek for starting

Comment: sorry for confusing you, I am calling it a commentary only as an insult. I also call some bad translations of the NET as commentary. Because this TPT is a very poor interpretative translation, going way different than the actual text. The further a text goes from the original in interpretation, it should be called commentary, not translation. Literal translations alone are the real ones. Even NIV and NLT are way better translations.

Comment: In those free bible apps I mentioned to you, you get all the BSB interlinear versions which is very good. As for textual variants you will get the basic idea from the footnotes from biblegateway site, or in the bible app versions. Apparatus will show some detailed analysis. Read the book by Metzger "The Text of the New Testament". The Mybible mobile app also has his textual variant commentary for free.

Comment: @Michael16 I am aware of the middle side note of the omission or addition of manuscript preference per the translation committee; yet I am grateful that you gave some “computer tools” for me to use.  I can reference those tools & Metzger’s Book.  Thanks.

Comment: note down or save the names, the long comments will be deleted by the admins.

Comment: @Michael16 Gotcha screen saved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here is the main reason for the variant TPT translation.  It's a matter of the masorah added to the text around the Masoretes added between the 7th to 10th century to preserve the pronunciation of the text.  The Masoretic Text (MT) has וְ֝אֵ֗ל (and God), but TPT changes the masorah to וְאַל (and not).  The Septuagint (LXX) seems to support this.  The consonants for the 2nd person in TPT are not present in the Hebrew text. The LXX dates before the 1st century B.C.  Thus, deciding which is original ("not" verses "God") is not trivial.  TPT also adds other words in the LXX and Vulgate, but not in the Hebrew.

> 12 ὁ θεὸς κριτὴς δίκαιος καὶ ἰσχυρὸς καὶ μακρόθυμος **μὴ** ὀργὴν ἐπάγων καθʼ ἑκάστην ἡμέραν.
> (Psalm 7:12, LXX; =7:11 in English translations)

Comment: thanks, the LXX is clearly better and more reasonable reading. I am assuming TPT is based on it, I am wondering the full form of TPT

Comment: @Perry Webb Appreciate the insight, +1